# Creating SFDC Opportunity using Partner WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl, salesforce

Is there a way to Create an Opportunity using Partner WSDL?
The only examples I see online is creating using Enterprise WSDL but they are specific to an organization.

Amongst Other links I have been referring to..
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/calls.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm#topic-title

Any help will be useful.

Thanks

-a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the section in the Web Services docs for the [PartnerAPI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_partner.htm) There's also examples on calling [create with the partner API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sample_create_call.htm) The sample creates a contact, but it works exactly the same way for an opportunity, just set the type to opportunity, and populate the fields array with your data.